# Как обработать сразу несколько строк из запроса бд?

Tags: python, aiogram

По сути вопрос простой, но мне в голову ничего уже не лезет.

```
async def todays(message):
    jbs = cur.execute(f'SELECT game,win FROM wins WHERE id = ?', (message.from_user.id,)).fetchall()
```

после запроса, в jbs может выйти такое: [(109, 89)] или  [(109, 89), (999, 990)] и тд.
Как вы могли понять, на выходе будет выдавать столько строк, сколько раз айди пользователя есть в колонке id бд.
В зависимости от запроса, мне нужно складывать первые и вторые значения каждого списка. По типу 109+999 и 89+990.

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT sum(game), sum(win) FROM wins WHERE id = ?'
```

Только уже не fetchall, а fetchone

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]